# Class library resolving error in endpoints-framework:discoveryDocs

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to migrate my project from endpoints v1 to endpoints v2 but cannot create discovery docs. running

```
$ mvn -DskipTests -X endpoints-framework:discoveryDocs
```

leads to a build failure

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs (default-cli) on project myproject: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs failed: A required class was missing while executing com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs: org/apache/commons/dbutils/ResultSetHandler
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm = plugin>com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/tools/endpoints-framework-maven-plugin/1.0.0/endpoints-framework-maven-plugin-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
...
```

I can see that the respective .jar file is in the -cp parameters:

```
..., /Users/me/.m2/repository/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils/1.6/commons-dbutils-1.6.jar, ...
```

but not in the error urls (`urls[0..48] = ...`)

Building and testing runs correctly (`mvn verify` etc), so the libraries do actually exist and work, but I think it cannot actually run without discovery docs.

Any ideas what I could have missed? There seem to be a huge number of .jar files in that classpath, is there some limit?

Comment: Got the same issue while migrating from Cloud Endpoints V1 to V2: `Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs failed: A required class was missing while executing com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-maven-plugin:1.0.0:discoveryDocs: com/googlecode/objectify/Work`. Objectify is a dependency in `pom.xml` and compilation works fine. Any news on this?

Comment: as a workaround, you can use the exec-maven-plugin to do a GetSwaggerDoc function (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend/pom.xml) which seemed to work for me. But naturally its not a nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the endpoints-framework-maven-plugin to version 1.0.1:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- plugin configuration -->
        <hostname>YOUR-APPP-ID.appspot.com</hostname>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There was a bug in version 1.0.0, see here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-maven-plugin/issues/32